# Algorithm to calculate the substring

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I am trying to learn to make efficient algorithms.
My code to find substring is as follows

```
 public static bool HasSubstring(string MainStr,string SubStr)
    {
        bool FoundMatch = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < MainStr.Length; i++)
        {

            if (SubStr.Length != 0)
            {
                int a = 0;
                int j = 0;
                if (MainStr[i] == SubStr[a])
                {
                    j = i;
                    do
                    {
                        if (MainStr[j] == SubStr[a])
                        {
                            a++;
                            j++;
                            FoundMatch = true;
                            continue;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            FoundMatch = false;
                            break;
                        }


                    } while (a<SubStr.Length);
                    if (FoundMatch == true)
                    {
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        return FoundMatch;


    }
```

can I Optimize this approach ?

Comment: [string contains?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx). Edit: if this is not about finding substrings and insteat about learning algorithms then you can return as soon as you've found a match

Comment: It seems that this would be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think this question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am sorry I didnt get you @Sayse

Comment: Also, your C# variables should usually be `lowercaseCamelCase`, not capitalized.

Comment: @Kyle, there is already a method to get a substring, (theres a link in my original comment)

Comment: @Sayse This is about learning algorithms

Comment: @C.Lang OK that part I missed..thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few of things I can see to improve this

- Before looping, check if the substring is 0 length, if so return false (dont check every iteration)
- Remove **ALL** `== true`'s its basically comparing a boolean against a boolean
- Use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) to find the first character of your substring (return false if result of indexOf is -1) and then use this index as the starting value for i
- I believe instead of the `j` variable you can just increment `i` but I've not tested this

  ```
  if (FoundMatch)
    return true;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have a look at following algorithms:

- Knuth Morris Pratt
- Rabin-Karp

These are some well known algorithms for pattern matching in a string if you want to find all the occurrences of the substring.

Comment: And don't forget Boyer-Moore

Answer (score 0):

To use Wile instead of Do While. The difference between the two loops is that the code in a Do loop will get executed at least once, because the while part is at the end. With the while part at the beginning, your end condition in round brackets can already be true (i might be more than loopEnd).
And I think you don't need continue.